# Mac OS X: What is making my system slow RIGHT NOW?

Tags: macos, performance, debugging, dtrace, energy

Question: is there a utility (command line or GUI) that will answer "what is making my Mac slow RIGHT NOW?"

I can see `CPU` percentage and `RPRVT` with `top` or `ActivityMonitor.app`.  And `Activity Monitor` will show me **aggregate** i/o info – but it won't show me per-process i/o, or i/o latencies.  There are dtrace scripts, like `iotop`, `iosnoop`, and `dtruss` that will show me i/o info.  And, of course, there is `fs_usage`.  And `stackshot`.  And etc., etc. !!!

**Note:** I am posting this question here on StackOverflow -- instead of, say AskDifferent or SuperUser -- because I see this as a **programming** question, not just a user/sysadmin question.  Extra points for: command line, open source, hackable, and/or dtrace scripts.

Summarizing, per discussion in comments:

I want a utility that **monitors** **recent** & **instantaneous** **CPU** and **I/O** load (**quantity**, **latency**) in a way that is both:

**unified** (i.e., both in the same display), and

**actionable** (by telling me which processes are incurring the aforementioned loads).

Comment: could be any number of things.  Too many open programs, not enough ram, slow ram, dust, slow hard drive, broken OS, cluttered OS, spotlight re-indexing, misc. gremlins, slow internet, page caching, firefox memory leak, a virtual machine running in the background, general overheating, poorly programmed applications/OS, it's been a few months since you last did a reboot, any combination thereof, or anything else not in this list.

You'll be hardpressed to find something that monitors everything and can pinpoint exactly what the problem is.

Comment: @RussellUhi You have completely missed the point of the question.  All of the high-level causes you have listed can be boiled down to CPU load or I/O load.  I will re-summarize the question: I want a utility that monitors recent & instantaneous CPU and I/O load (quantity, latency) in a unified and actionable fashion.

Comment: Have you tried `sysdiagnose`? You can also invoke it with a hot key combo: [shift][control][option][⌘][.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this slideshow from Brendan Gregg for some strategies: http://www.slideshare.net/brendangregg/analyzing-os-x-systems-performance-with-the-use-method

Though I believe that you have answered your own question. dtrace is exactly the tool you are looking for.

dtrace allows you to observe pretty much *everything* that is happening with your system.

It operates on the principle of dynamically inserted probes in running software that can report all kinds of data about whats happening.

The scripts you mention are only a small, but useful, starting point. 
I dont think there is a dtrace script that is already that will do exactly what you want, however it would not be terribly difficult to write one.  What you need to do is learn how to write D scripts, and learn what probes you want to use to get at the info you seek. You can write probes that aggregate data, and you can write probes that provide realtime info. Its up to you, and the sky's really the limit.

I would start by looking some of the tools here: http://www.brendangregg.com/dtracetoolkit.html
and learning what they do and how they work, and you should be able to build yourself the tool you need shortly.

The D language itself is somewhat like C, so fairly easy to pick up if you're familiar with any C based languages. But even if you arent writing in D, there are some extremely useful one liners that can reach into your system and give you the information you seek.

An additional advantage to learning how to use dtrace and D is that there are probes for many, many application layer things out there, such as mysql, php, javascript, ruby, perl, java etc etc etc. Its like a performance analysis tool that can get really deep. For example: this simple oneliner showed me all of the mysql queries my server was running:

```
sudo dtrace -n 'mysql*:::query-start { trace(copyinstr(arg0)) }'
```

TL;DR dtrace can tell you *anything* that is happening on your OSX system. You just have to learn how to ask it.

Comment: Forgot to add https://wikis.oracle.com/display/DTrace/Documentation - for the D language

Comment: I adore Dtrace.  You have given an excellent answer for a different question, maybe, "What would be a good way to go about writing such utility **from scratch**?"  I am looking for a higher-level tool with the functionality of `iotop` + `top` (at least).  What I'm trying to **avoid** is writing such a thing **from scratch** … although I would like the **option** of hacking on it to tweak it.

Comment: The question was "what is making my Mac slow RIGHT NOW?", and you are assuming that the answer is either CPU, or IO, when really the answer is more complicated than that. You might try looking at Instruments, that comes with Xcode. But I would thumb through this slideshow from brendangregg: http://www.slideshare.net/brendangregg/analyzing-os-x-systems-performance-with-the-use-method.

Comment: Ultimately, the answer cannot be more complicated than "CPU or I/O".  There is nothing else to wait on. (I'm lumping cache (and TLB) thrashing into the "CPU" category, but you could add a third category, "Memory Hierarchy".)  The only "complicated" aspect of it is the (transitive) dependencies between processes (threads, whatever).  I.e., if I'm trying to do X, and X is asking Y for something, and etc.... But for the purpose of this question I'm less concerned about the "blame trail" -- which might be important if I were trying to **fix** the issue, and not just **isolate** it.

Comment: **That slideshow from brendangregg is by far the best answer I've received so far.  Could you or I edit your answer to include the pointer to it right at the beginning of it?** Thank you!!!

Comment: Edited. Yeah, that is a great slideshow. I learn fistloads every time I go to his site or read any of his blog posts.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `Instruments.app` that is bundled with Developer Tools for mac (namely Xcode). Specifically the [Activity Monitor](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AnalysisTools/Reference/Instruments_User_Reference/ActivityMonitorInstrument/ActivityMonitorInstrument.html).

Furthermore, I recommend you to explore this app since it has lots of useful templates from the box and you can even extend it with your own dtrace scripts.